# What are bpf maps used for?

Tags: bpf, ebpf

Can eBPF maps be used to share information between two functions?

For example: get process name from one function; and if `processname == "something"` drop the packet using XDP.

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BPF maps are used to retain information between two executions of BPF programs. So what you're describing is one possible use case.

Examples of map usage can be found in [the Linux samples](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/samples/bpf) and in [the bcc examples](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/tree/master/examples).

Answer (score 1):

Adding two reference links to pchaigno's answer, [ebpf.io](https://ebpf.io/what-is-ebpf#maps) and Cilium's [BPF and XDP reference guide](https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/#maps).